# Find Equation of Parabola

Tags: geometry

I am trying to get my head around parabolas and running into bit of a wall.
I've been trying to figure out what the formula for a parabola would be given that i have 2 points on Cartesian plane $(14.5,35)$, $(7, 34.5)$.

I know equation is $y=ax^2+bx+c$ but still doesn't help me, my maths is very rusty.

Summary:
How to find the formula of a parabola using the two points $A(14.5,35)$ and $B(7, 34.5)$?

Thanks for help guys.

Comment: In fact, we need three points non-collinear to determine a parabola.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a parabola $\;y=x^2+bx+c\;$ through the points $\;(14.5\,,\,35)\;,\;\;(7\,,\,34.5)\;$ . Substituting

$$\begin{align*}&35=14.5^2+14.5b+c\\{}\\
&34.5=7^2+7b+c\end{align*}$$

Substract the equations and get:

$$\frac12=161.25+7.5b$$

Solve, substitute back and get $\;c\;$ and you're done.

Observe that above $\;a=1\;$ . The solution you get can be scaled to get several parabolas through those two points., of course.